# Logic Puzzle: Every 2nd-order Injection has a Left Inverse

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic, second-order-logic

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple days.

We know that every set theoretic injections have a left inverse:
$$\forall x,y(f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y)$$

Iff ...
$$\exists g:\text{im}(f)\to\text{dom}(f)\forall x(g\circ f(x)=x)$$

I have been trying to prove the same for second-order "injections".

$$\forall x,y(Fx=Fy\implies x=y)$$

Iff

$$\exists_FG\forall x(GFx=x)$$

Briefly, my tools are ...

**Axiom of Choice**
$$\forall_PP(\forall x\exists yPxy\implies \exists_FF\forall xPxFx)$$

**Theorem: Partial Function**
$$\forall_P P,Q(\forall x(Px\implies \exists yQxy)\implies\exists_FF \forall x(Px\implies QxFx))$$

**Theorem: Unique Function**
$$\forall_PP(\forall x\exists! yPxy\implies\exists!_FF\forall xPxFx)$$

**Theorem: Surjection iff Right Inverse**
$$\forall_FF(\forall x\exists y(Fy=x)\iff\exists_F G\forall x(FGx=x))$$

**Axiom of Comprehension**
$$\exists_PP\forall\langle x\rangle_n(P^n\langle x\rangle_n\iff\Phi\langle x\rangle_n)$$

Where $\Phi$ is any formula and $\langle x\rangle_n$ is $n$ variables.

In addition, all first-order with equality axioms are theorems.

This is for my personal study, so there is no guarantee that this is proveable.

But there is so little study into second-order logic, I think any answer would be appreciated by many.

**My Attempts at a Proof**

Assumption:
$$Fx=Fy\implies x=y$$

I know by first-order logic that there is some c for any arbitrary variable x:
$$x=c$$

Therefore, by consequent's conditional:
$$Fx=y\implies x=c$$

By comprehension we can define a predicate from here:
$$Pyz$$

Existential generalization
$$\exists zPyz$$

Universal generalization on $y$
$$\forall y\exists zPyz$$

We can use choice now:
$$\exists_FG\forall yPyGy$$

And convert it back to a formula:
$$\forall y(Fx=y\implies x=Gy)$$

Now choose $y$ to be $Fx$:
$$Fx=Fx\implies x=GFx$$

Therefore ...
$$x=GFx$$

And

$$GFx=x$$

Now existential generalization ...
$$\exists_FG(GFx=x)$$

Universal generalization...
$$\forall x\exists_FG(GFx=x)$$

But NO! I need ...
$$\exists_F G\forall x(GFx=x)$$

This is where I get stuck. I know I must use the assumption somehow but I don't know how.

I can prove:
$$\forall x(\exists_y(Fy=x)\iff \exists!y(Fy=x))$$

And from here maybe(?) I can do something. But I don't know. I'm stuck.

Comment: It will help if you first write down a less formal version of the proof and then figure out how to express each part using the formal tools you have. You have two directions of the "iff" to prove. For the forward direction, you need to define $G$ as a function that takes each element in the image if $F$ to one of its preimages, then use injectivity of $F$ to show that $G$ has the desired property. For the reverse direction, notice that if $Fx=Fy$ then $x=GFx=GFy=y$.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it, I created a function $G$ using a similar method as above such that $$\forall y(\exists x(Fx=y)\implies\exists c(Fc=y\land Gy=c))$$ After this, I assumed $\exists z\neg(Fz=y\implies Gy=z)$. This led to a contradiction by the injective propery so $\forall z(Fz=y\implies Gy=z)$ and $\forall z,y(Fz=y\implies Gy=z)$. From here I instantiated $z$ to be an arbitrary $x$ $$\forall y(Fx=y\implies Gy=x)$$ I then chose $y$ to be $Fx$ $$Fx=Fx\implies GFx=x$$ and thus $$\forall x(GFx=x)$$